# How to change the a specific value of a row of a pandas Series?

Tags: pandas, series

I have the following pandas Series:

```
   trade                          dtype
trade_action                   category
execution_venue                  object
from_implied                      int64
```

In the last row I would like to change the `from_implied` name to `implied`. How can I do this?

Expected output:

```
   trade                          dtype
trade_action                   category
execution_venue                  object
   implied                       int64
```

Comment: Is that a pd.Series or a pd.DataFrame?   Can you put the code to construct your input data here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
ser = pd.Series(["trade","trade_Action","execution_venue","from_implied"])
ser2 = ser.replace(to_replace = "from_implied", value = "implied")
```

With ser.replace you can change the values of a pd.Series as above.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first column is your Series' index, you can use the [`pd.Series.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) method on your series:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your series here
series = pd.read_clipboard().set_index("trade")["dtype"]

out = series.rename({"from_implied": "implied"})
```

out:

```
trade
trade_action       category
execution_venue      object
implied               int64
Name: dtype, dtype: object
```